# Setting a length with a key to a TikZ node

Tags: pgfkeys

I would like to create some split rectangles whose widths are defined by the length of a designated line.  I would like to do this through a key such as in:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\newlength\aetmplength

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  set text to width of/.code={%%
    \settowidth\aetmplength{#1}%%
    \typeout{--->`#1`::\the\aetmplength}%%
    \pgfkeysalso{text width=\the\aetmplength}%%
  },
  ]
  \node[draw,
        shape=rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        set text to width of=This is the top of the node,
        %text width=0.95in
        ] () 
        {
         This is the top of the node
         \nodepart{two}
           first item\\
           second item\\
           \ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But this doesn't work.  I could easily spend sometime working around this.  So this isn't a problem of how to set the length I want.  What I want to understand is why this definition for the key isn't doing what I want it to do.

Comment: It is `\nullfont` inside the tikz picture.

Comment: @percusse I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  What's `\nullfont`?  And whatever that is, is there a way to work around it?

Comment: Sorry my mistaken presumption.  I meant:  `\nullfont` is the primitive, roughly speaking, that maps the font definition to zero. Hence in the code, your text input is expanded to zero width as text is mapped to nullfont. You can place things into a temporary box and measure its width instead. TikZ does that to ignore any dangling text commands etc. within the picture.

Comment: @percusse I don't think I'm getting what you're talking about.  I tried something along the lines of `\settowidth\aetmplength{\mbox{#1}}` and I tried `\sbox\aetmpbox{#1}\aetmplength\wd\aetmpbox`, but neither approach is working.

Comment: Try this as the code of the key : `\pgfutil@selectfont\settowidth\aetmplength{#1}\pgfkeysalso{text width=\the\aetmplength}`

Comment: @percusse That works.  Unfortunately there is no documentation for `\pgfutil@selectfont`.  Care to write up an answer?  Where did you find this macro?

Comment: @percusse Interestingly enough, `\pgfutil@selectfont` appears to expand to `\protect\selectfont` and yet, when I replace `\pgfutil@selectfont` with `\protect\selectfont` things break once more.  Any clue?

Comment: I read a lot of PGF code some time ago, that's how I remember it. And as I tried to show below its meaning is context dependent on `\nullfont` activation.

Answer (score 10):

The explanation, that TikZ is using `\nullfont` is already given in percusse's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242070/16967). Therefore `\settowidth` will not work as expected.

### `\pgfmathsetlength{width("#1")}`

Instead of `\settowidth` the `pgfmath` function `width` can be used instead:

```
\pgfmathsetlength\aetmplength{width("#1")}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\newlength\aetmplength

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  set text to width of/.code={%%
    % \settowidth\aetmplength{#1}%%
    \pgfmathsetlength\aetmplength{width("#1")}%
    \typeout{--->`#1`::\the\aetmplength}%%
    \pgfkeysalso{text width=\the\aetmplength}%%
  },
  ] 
  \node[draw,
        shape=rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        set text to width of=This is the top of the node,
        %text width=0.95in
        ] ()
        {   
         This is the top of the node
         \nodepart{two}
           first item\\
           second item\\
           \ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### `\pgftext{...}`

Another way is `\pgftext`, which escapes back to TeX, where `\settowidth` will work again. Since the argument of `\pgftext` is processed inside a group, `\aetmplength` is assigned globally and `\setwidth` act on a local temporary dimen register. Local and global assignments should not be mixed on the same control sequence for memory reasons.

```
\pgftext{%
  \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%%
  \global\aetmplength=\dimen0\relax
}%
```

### `node font`

The latest version can also be used to respect the value of option `node font`. The value is stored in macro `\tikz@node@textfont`. Without `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` the control sequence can also be specified by `\csname` and `\endcsname`:

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\newlength\aetmplength

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node font=\tiny,
  set text to width of/.code={%%
    \pgftext{%
      \csname tikz@node@textfont\endcsname
      \settowidth{\dimen0}{#1}%%
      \global\aetmplength=\dimen0\relax
    }%
    \typeout{--->`#1`::\the\aetmplength}%%
    \pgfkeysalso{text width=\the\aetmplength}%%
  },
  ] 
  \node[draw,
        shape=rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        set text to width of=This is the top of the node,
        %text width=0.95in
        ] ()
        {   
         This is the top of the node
         \nodepart{two}
           first item\\
           second item\\
           \ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with node font setting]

Answer (score 9):

TikZ/PGF design is done in such a way that its regular syntax doesn't have any spurious whitespace leaks or unintended characters are printed out inside the code etc. One way of doing it is to map the current font to the special primitive `\nullfont`.

This causes that you cannot simply handle text width without recreating the original non-`\nullfont` state. Just to give some context, below is taken from the `pgf@picture` environment `begin` definition:

```
    \begingroup%
      \let\pgf@setlengthorig=\setlength%
      \let\pgf@addtolengthorig=\addtolength%
      \let\pgf@selectfontorig=\selectfont%  <== Records the original
      \let\setlength=\pgf@setlength%
      \let\addtolength=\pgf@addtolength%
      \let\selectfont=\pgf@selectfont% <== Overwrites
      \nullfont\spaceskip0pt\xspaceskip0pt% <== Resets font
      \setbox\pgf@layerbox@main\hbox to0pt\bgroup%
        \begingroup%
```

Once we know this then you can temporarily go back to original definition inside a group get the width and survive the group.

```
\documentclass[border=4pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{set text to width of/.code={%%
\begingroup%
\pgfutil@selectfont%
\settowidth\pgf@xc{#1}% <== PGF internal scratch registers xa,ya,xb,yb,xc,yc
\edef\temp{\noexpand\pgfkeysalso{text width=\the\pgf@xc}}%<- Nonzero
\expandafter\endgroup\temp%%
\typeout{--->`#1`::\the\pgf@xc}%<-Still zero!
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw,
        align=center,%<- for line breaks
        shape=rectangle split,
        rectangle split parts=2,
        set text to width of=This is looooooooonnnnnnnnger than the top,
        ] () 
        {
         This is the top of the node
         \nodepart{two}
           first item\\
           second item\\
           \ldots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]